# Installing Team Foundation Server separate from SQL Server: error TF255040

Tags: sql-server-2008, team-foundation-server, sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Database, Reporting and Analysis Services installed on **Server A**. On **Server B**, I am trying to configure Team Foundation Server using the Advanced Configuration Wizard. Pretty much everything seems to be okay except for the Analysis Services part. When I set my SQL Server Analysis Services Instance path and try to test it, I receive the following error message:

> TF255040: You must exit the Team Foundation Admin console and install SQL Server Reporting Services or at a minimum SQL Client Connectivity Tools on the application tier to ensure Analysis Services object model is present for warehouse processing. Once you have installed the necessary reporting components, re-start the admin console and re-run the wizard.

Well, I don't want to install the SQL Server Reporting Services on Server B. As far as SQL Client Connectivity Tools, I am not sure what it is referring to. Should I install the SQL Server Management Studio on Server B?

*Note: I have enabled the firewall exception for Analysis Services on Server A and I am able to connect to it from another machine.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Client Tools Connectivity" is one of the available SQL Server shared install options you can choose locally without installing any of the server components.

Run the SQL Server installer and ensure you deselect everything else (that you have not installed to provide connectivity).

> Should I install the SQL Server Management Studio on Server B?

You don't need this on the application tier, but if it is there it can be used for remote management of your data tier.